# check for repeated data in incoming csv file before loading to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Database: MySQL

I have a temporary table where all incoming data are loaded from a CSV file.
I have a master table where data is transferred from the temporary table.
Now, i need to check that if any row in temporary table already exist in master table.
If it exists, i need to update the data in master table
else, i need to insert that row to master table.

The problem to me here is there is not pk column in temporary table so that i can know which row to compare between temp and master table.

Is there any way to check about already existing row without primary key?
there is no guarantee that any column will be unique.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the decision to the master table.

From MySQL documentation

```
INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
[INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
SELECT ...
[ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_name=expr, ... ]
```

So if you do `INSERT INTO` yourMasterTable `SELECT` fromYourTempTable `ON DUPLICATE KEY` ... will handle your needs